# ActiveX dependencies in Access

Tags: ms-access, crystal-reports, activex, dependencies, dll

I'm using the Crystal Reports Viewer 11 ActiveX control in an Access form (version 2007, 2003 format).  Everything works well on my development machine, where I have CRXI installed.  I copied the referenced DLL to the client's machine, but when I try to register it, it says "Can't find module" (I double- and triple-checked my spelling) and when I try to open the form it tells me "ActiveX component can't create object" when the code tries to create a new instance of the report object.  I suspect there are more dependency files required by the DLL, but I'm a little at a loss as to what ones and how I go about finding out.  Although I'm using the CR control, I assume this would apply to any ActiveX control throwing this error.  Thanks.

Comment: What are you using to distribute your Access app? The Access package and deploy wizard should resolve all the depencies for you and include all the referenced DLLs in the installer, and then register them on install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question in case someone finds this via a search in the future.  I don't have the Access Package & Deploy wizard David mentioned above (okay, I probably have it but couldn't find it readily) but I image it would probably do what I needed, so I recommend anyone try that first.  Instead, I was able to create a setup to install tghe needed files using the Visual Studio Installer and the Crystal merge modules; note that while it wasn't difficult, nor was it pleasant.

I downloaded and installed [Visual Studio Installer 1.1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=5FBBC453-CD04-4562-A66E-5C21436E6F56&displaylang=en) from MSDN.  This creates a new project type in Visual Studio 6.0 (in particular, I used InterDev 6.0) that creates a Windows Installer (*.msi) setup file.  Because one of the Crystal merge modules requires the Crystal license key and VSI doesn't support merge module parameters, I also had to use Orca, a merge module editor, available from the [Microsoft Windows SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=4377F86D-C913-4B5C-B87E-EF72E5B4E065&displaylang=en) (also available on the Microsoft download site).  I recommend reading through the SDK and Orca pages on MSDN for more info. Using Orca, I was able to put my key code and recompile the merge module, so I don't have to deploy my key to my users, and my users don't have to enter one.

Again, the Package & Deployment Wizard is probably a better option, but when faced with using merge modules, as with Crystal, this method will get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a runtime distribution document in your Crystal Help files - from past experience (Crystal 8.5) there are multiple files that you have to distribute and register.